# R - How can I filter by a particular item (one of several) inside a column of a data frame

Tags: r, string, dataframe

So I have a dataframe with, say, 3 columns.

[Heres the example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b5ZB.jpg)

One of these columns (String) is essentially a charachter vector with multiple items. So one row of the column looks like - ("ABCD", "A", "AB") and another column could look like ("XYZ", "Q", "ABCD"), and yet another would be ("AB", "A")

Now I want to be able to filter in such a way that I see results for all columns with only "ABCD"(so in the above example, only the first and second column and not the third one).

How would I go about this?

I've tried group_by and filter functions using dplyr, but these do not consider each value of the string independantly (so it considers  ("ABCD", "A", "AB") as a whole and not just "ABCD".

Comment: please improve your question by adding an example that everyone can copy and paste reproducibly into their own environment

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using `purrr::map`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tribble(~Name, ~Numeric, ~String,
              "Python", 9, c("ABCD", "A", "AB"),
              "R", 14, c("XYZ", "Q", "ABCD"),
              "Java", 3, c("AB", "A"))


df |>
    filter(map_lgl(String, ~"ABCD" %in% .x))

##> + # A tibble: 2 × 3
##>   Name   Numeric String   
##>   <chr>    <dbl> <list>   
##> 1 Python       9 <chr [3]>
##> 2 R           14 <chr [3]>
```